# CurrentItem not set when using paging

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a DataGrid with CurrentItem bound on a property. DataGrid has implemented Paging.

If I select items in the first page, CurrentItem changes and everything is fine. However, when I set another page... I change Observable collection to display another 30 rows, the CurrentItem binding does not sork.

I have:

`<DataGrid CurrentItem="{Binding CurrentItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}">`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, I'm following your question - but, I'll take a wild guess :-). I'm guessing your problem is that the CurrentItem is no longer set (and no row is selected in the DataGrid) unless you manually select a new item in the DataGrid? If that is the case, you simply need to add a property in your DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

This will force the DataGrid to select the first item when data is reloaded.

Another wild guess:

When you set the new source - how do you do that? if you update your property with a new ObservableCollection without calling a PropertyChanged event your binding will no longer work (but then, your DataGrid shouldn't update either).

Hope, either of those help - otherwise, I need more info to help you :-).